# When do we need FormMethod.Get while overloading the @using(Html.BeginForm())?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

//code

}
```

I've seen that form is  used for submission of the data. To get the page we use [HttpGet] as an attribute for the Action and another action with the same name uses [HttpPost]. What is the case scenario which makes use of FormMethod.Get in the view page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, whenever you want to use a form with `method="get"`. Google uses this for their search, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `FormMethod` as `Get` instead of `Post` then the form will be posted and hit your `HttpGet` controller action with parameters will be shown in your **url**, generally used in search as pointed by @CodeCaster.